# Executing Rscript from Java

Tags: java, r, exception, rserve

I am trying to execute a R script from Java file.

Java code

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    RConnection connection = null;

    try {
        /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
         * 6311
         */
        connection = new RConnection();

        /* Note four slashes (\\\\) in the path */
        connection.eval("source(\'D:/r script/arima with upper limit final.R\')");
        //connection.eval("Rserve()");
        int lim1=2500;
        int lim2=2700;
        REXP sum=connection.eval("testfunction()");
       //System.out.println("The sum is=" +);
    } catch (RserveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    //}
}
```

R Script

```
testfunction = function(){
   lim1 = 2500
   lim2 = lim1+400
   start =lim2
   modeldata = as.vector(x$Mean.F3Amp)
   alarm = as.vector(x$Mean.F3HW)
   alarmpart = as.ts(alarm[lim1:lim2])
   predictalarm = alarmpart
   datapart = as.ts(modeldata[lim1:lim2])
   fit = Arima(datapart,order = c(3,1,1))
   modelforecast = forecast(fit,30)

   uppervaluemean = mean(modelforecast$upper[,2])

   prevMean = mean(tail(datapart,30))
   newMean =mean(modelforecast$mean)
   alarmMean = mean(tail(alarmpart,30))
   if(abs(alarmMean-uppervaluemean)>=0.01)
   {
   uppervaluemean =uppervaluemean+0.005
   predictalarm = c(predictalarm,rep.int(uppervaluemean,30))
   } else
   {
   predictalarm = c(predictalarm,rep.int(alarmMean,30))
   print("Else")
   }

   plot(modelforecast,xlim=c(0,lim2-lim1+30),ylim=c(0,0.6))
   lines(alarmpart,col=3)

   lines(predictalarm,col=5)

  filename = paste("D:/Plots123/plot",toString(iteration),".jpg",sep="")
  dev.copy(jpeg,filename=filename)
  dev.off()
  TRUE
}
```

I am new to RServe. The following is the error I get.

> org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
>       at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:234)
>       at pkg.Temp.main(Temp.java:23)

Line 23: `REXP sum=connection.eval("testfunction()");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it isn't recommended to call user-defined functions just-like that as they are hard to debug. Right now it is hard to say where the R-script evaluation fails.

But right-off-the-bat it's easy to see that the script might not be evaluated properly since there are external variables such as `x`, that might not be present in the Rserve working environment. Also libraries such as `forecast, fpp` might not have been imported, but are being used inside the function. You probably need to make some code changes in the script, which might include lines like:

```
library(forecast)
library(fpp)
x<-5 #or whatever x is
```

and then define your function below all the above.

Try using this which might help point out the error:

```
REXP sum = connection.parseAndEval("try("+testfunction()+",silent=TRUE)");
if (sum.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+sum.asString());
```

Comment: Arima is not a user defined function.. I will try adding the libraris which i am missing in the code